# Git Bash Closes Immediately on Windows 10 PC

Tags: git, bash

On Tuesday, my Git Bash app on my computer started to close when I would open the app on my PC.

When I open the app, the cursor will blink for a couple of seconds then close Git Bash automatically. [This is what I see right before Git Bash closes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egrhf.jpg) I uninstalled Git and reinstalled it, but Git Bash still closes after a few seconds.

I double checked my environment variables to make sure what I had set for the PATH and double checked my version of Git Bash.

Right now my PATH in System Variables is set to C:\Path\To\Git\2.1.7\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd.
I am taking coding classes online and one of my teachers suggested I look at [the Git-Bash Command Prompt won't open after upgrading to Windows 10 article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31887503/git-bash-command-prompt-wont-open-up-after-upgrading-to-windows-10) to see if I was able to get it to work.

I tried both of the suggestions given in the article, however Git Bash won't stay open.

Should I reset my PATH for systems variables? 
I have a PC with Windows 10 and Git Bash was working just fine with the latest version until now. 
Are there any ways I can check for bugs in Git Bash?

Comment: Try running it from cmd.exe and see if it gives more of a message...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

git bash was considerably improved since 2.1.7.

Uncompress [`PortableGit-2.6.4-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.6.4.windows.1/PortableGit-2.6.4-64-bit.7z.exe) in c:\prgs\git, and add to your PATH (removing first any git occurrences)

```
c:\prgs\git
c:\prgs\git\bin
c:\prgs\git\usr\bin
```

Then open a cmd, and see if `git-bash` is working.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but I didn't work. I uncompressed the file in the area you suggested and tried adding what you suggested in the PATH. However Git Bash still won't open? I put the c:\prgs\git\usr\bin in PATH under system variables? Did I need to add anything to user variables?

Comment: @SarahBartley The best practice is to declare a user environment PATH with only `c:\prgs\git;c:\prgs\git\bin;c:\prgs\git\usr\bin` in it. No need to change anything in system environment variables.

Comment: @SarahBartley But first, before changing anything, try first to open a CMD and type: `set PATH=Path=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\prgs\git;C:\prgs\git\bin;C:\prgs\git\usr\bin`. Then try in that CMD windows to see if `git-bash` works.

Comment: I opened the CMD and typed exactly set PATH=Path=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\Sys‌​tem32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\prgs\git;C:\prgs\git\bin;C:\prgs\git\usr\bin, but git bash wouldn't open. Did I need to include the ; in the code? Next, I replaced the PATH in the user variables with c:\prgs\git;c:\prgs\git\bin;c:\prgs\git\usr\bin, but that didn't work. Did you want me to create a brand new user variable for the user environment PATH?

Comment: @SarahBartley Sorry, I meant: `set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\Sys‌​tem32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\prgs\git;C:\prgs\git\bin;C:\prgs\git\usr\bin`. Typed in a CMD Windows, it only changes the PATH for that session, allowing you to test it out without having to change the user or system variable environments.

Comment: I typed set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\Sys‌​tem‌​32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\prgs\git;C:\prgs\git\bin;C:\prgs\git\usr\bin exactly in the CMD like you suggested then I used git bash to see if it would open Git Bash. The Git Bash window opened, but it still closes after a few seconds. I typed everything on the same line and used the ; too. Did you want me to type it as one thing or did you want me to type everything separately?

Comment: @SarahBartley do you have a .profile or .bashrc in %USERPROFILE% folder?

Comment: I have a .bashrc in one of my user folders.

Comment: @SarahBartley What does that `.bashrc` include? Can you try and move it temporarely, just to see if the git bash opens *without* that `.bashrc` being there?

Comment: I clicked on the file and inside it just says this : if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi. I moved the file temporarily into another folder, but Git Bash didn't open. There are other .bashrc such as .bashrc.swo and another file that doesn't have a name, but is classified as a BASHRC File. Do I need to do anything with those files?

Comment: @SarahBartley you can move them as well: let's make sure there is no side effects form those file.

Comment: Should I move these files into their own separate folder? Or do I need to go into these files and change something in particular?

Comment: @SarahBartley no, just move them in a temporay folder, for testing if that imprives the situation.

Comment: I noticed that some of the icons for the .bash files are either the notepad icon or ones with a page with a folded corner. Do I need to make sure the icons look the same? I did move all .bash files to a separate folder. How do I I check to see if there are any side effects?

Comment: @SarahBartley "How do I I check to see if there are any side effects?": simply by trying git-bash.exe again.

Comment: I just opened Git Bash and it worked! I typed in a few commands and ran one of my apps just to make sure. So far everything is running smoothly! Thank you for your help!

Comment: @SarahBartley Great news! Glad it is working for you.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem to make folder named 'etc' in

'C:\Windows\System32\drivers' folder.

As s result the path will be

'C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc'

Right click to open git bash on window explorer.
Close bash window and reopen.

If you ask me this solving applies to everybody? I don't know.
I updated latest version of git 2.19 yesterday and the same problem above occurred.
I'm worry about you misunderstand my words. Because I'm not good at English.

Answer (score 0):

Just try the command `bash -c sh` in cmd, does that work? If so then either you will see a link from where you need to install ubuntu of other linux flavours if not then you need to install the ubuntu or any other linux flavour from microsoft store of your windows. After installing it then you can launch it after installation and do rest of the work you need to do in linux bash.

Comment: I'm having the same issue although I'm running on Windows 11. I saw the suggestion to turn on developer mode which I did. Then tried that and got the following result:
C:\Users\md>bash -c sh
<3>WSL (8) ERROR: CreateProcessParseCommon:754: getpwuid(0) failed 2
Processing fstab with mount -a failed.

<3>WSL (8) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:331: getpwuid(0) failed 2
<3>WSL (8) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:502: execvpe /bin/bash failed 2
<3>WSL (8) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:505: Create process not expected to return

Answer (score 0):

It is because Windows Subsystem for Linux has no installed distributions on your PC/Laptop.

Distributions can be installed by visiting the Microsoft Store or via this [link](https://aka.ms/wslstore) and you can choose the Linux distribution you want.

After that, you will simply be able to open your bash window normally.